# Error in class(ff) <- "formula" : attempt to set an attribute on NULL when running mrds models in R

Tags: r, model

I am analysing a mark-recapture distance sample (mrds) project.
I have used a loop to compared multiple point independence models to trial mark-recapture (mr) covariates.
I then fit the best covariate fit into the mr model.
I then used a loop to include covariates in the ds model with the mr covariate model.
When I run the loop to find the best fit (covariates) for the ds model I get the following error:

```
Error in class(ff) <- "formula" : attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

The code I used to get this error is:

```
ds.formula <- c("~size","~team","~Region.Label","~side","size+side","~size+team",
                "~size+region","~size+team+region")
num.ds.models <- length(ds.formula)
pi.results <- data.frame(DSmodel=ds.formula, AIC=rep(NA,num.ds.models))
for (i in 1:num.ds.models) {
  pi.model <- ddf(method='io', mrmodel=~glm(link='logit',formula=~size),
                  dsmodel=~mcds(key='hn',formula=as.formula(ds.formula[i])), 
                  data=animals, meta.data=list(width=300))
  pi.results$AIC[i] <- summary(pi.model)$AIC
}
```

I have run this analysis using smaller sections of the data and it ran fine without errors, but with the larger dataset I get the above error.

Is the issue with the code or my data? What would be the best solution to solve the issue?